# Is it appropriate to use reflection to create a list of objects of all subclasses?

Tags: java, reflection

In my program, different features are divided into different modules, potentially hundreds of modules,
each module is a subclass of an abstract Module class
which look something like this

```
public abstract class Module {

    public final String name;

    public Module(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public abstract void execute();
}
```

with subclasses that look like this

```
public class Mod1 extends Module{
    public Mod1() {
        super("Mod1");
    }

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

and I need to make a list of instances of all modules but doing it like this is kinda tedious since my program might have hundreds of modules and it might be hard to debug(I might miss a few lol)

```
private static final List<Module> MODULES = new ArrayList<>();

public void init(){
    MODULES.add(new Mod1());
    MODULES.add(new Mod2());
    MODULES.add(new Mod3());
    MODULES.add(new Mod4());
    MODULES.add(new Mod5());
}
```

so I think using reflection might be the way to go but after a quick google search, I see many people don't like reflection in production code, so I come here to ask if this is an appropriate case to use reflection or is there any reason or design change to avoid using reflection in this particular case

edit: the list will be used stuff like rendering modules in gui or calling execute method of the module from other user interface like command(simply find the module with matching name and execute it)

note: this is not how my code actually look like but a highly simplified version that give a similar idea

Comment: This particular situation can be resolved by using a [`ServiceLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/ServiceLoader.html). However, since we don't know the purpose of the "list of instances", this feels like it could also be an [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: the list will be used for different kind of stuff like rendering modules in gui or calling execute method of the module from other user interface like command(simply find the module with matching name and execute it)

Answer (score 0):

For a minimal-effort approach, java provides the built-in class [`java.util.ServiceLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/ServiceLoader.html).

With this class you can obtain all *available* implementations of a service class (in this case `Module`) like

```
ServiceLoader moduleLoader = ServiceLoader.load(Module.class);
for (Module mod : moduleLoader) {
    System.out.println(mod.name);
}
```

Note that I highlighted the term *available* in the previous sentence. In fact, the `ServiceLoader` implementation does not perform any advanced class-hierarchy lookup, instead it relies on a specific resource file named equal to the canonical name of the `Module` class.

`META-INF/services/com.example.project.Module`

```
com.example.project.impl1.Module1
com.example.project.impl2.Module2
```

Where each line of the file references an *available* implementation of `Module`.

---

Now, `ServiceLoader` is an implementation of the [java SPI specification](https://www2.cs.duke.edu/csed/java/jdk1.4.2/docs/guide/jar/jar.html#Service%20Provider), which does not necessarily have to qualify perfectly for your use case. However, since its idea of service loading and providing is rather simple, you can easily build your own variant.

```
public class JsonServiceLoader<S> {

    private Class<S> service;
    private Map<String, String> serviceIdentifiers;

    public static <T> JsonServiceLoader load(Class<T> service, ClassLoader cl) {
        Map<String, String> serviceIdentifiers = new HashMap<>();
        String name = "META-INF/json-services/" + service.getCanonicalName();
        // TODO check for null references where necessary
        for (Enumeration<URL> resources = cl.getResources(name); resources.hasMoreElements();) {
            try (InputStream resource = resources.next().openStream()) {
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> identifier : parseJson(resource).entrySet()) {
                    serviceIdentifers.merge(
                        identifer.getKey(),
                        identifer.getValue(),
                        (value1, value2) -> throw new ServiceConfigurationError(
                            "duplicate service identifier '" + identifier.getKey() + "'"
                        );
                    );
                }
            }
        }
        return new JsonServiceLoader<>(service, serviceIdentifiers);
    }

    private static Map<String, String> parseJson(InputStream resource) {
        // TODO parse JSON data from the given stream using your favourite JSON facility
        /*
         * If you want to use a different style of resources, e.g. XML, this is the only
         * location you have to change (you might want to rename 'json-services' though).
         */
        return new HashMap<>();
    }

    private JsonServiceLoader(Class<S> service, Map<String, String> serviceIdentifiers) {
        this.service = service;
        this.serviceIdentifiers = serviceIdentifiers;
    }

    public Set<String> getServiceIdentifiers() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(serviceIdentifiers.keySet());
    }

    public S getService(String name) {
        String className = serviceIdenfiers.get(name);
        if (null == className) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid service identifier '" + name + "'");
        }
        // TODO improve error handling
        try {
            return service.cast(Class.forName(className).newInstance());
        } catch(Exception exc) {
            throw new ServiceConfigurationError("could not load service '" + name + "'", exc);
        }
    }

}
```

Your `JSON` resources could look like

`META-INF/json-services/com.example.project.Module`

```json
{
    "Mod1" : {
        "class" : "com.example.project.impl1.Module1"
    },
    "Mod2" : {
        "class" : "com.example.project.impl2.Module2"
    }
}
```

allowing future extensions.

At this point, the `Module` class also does not need to know its name (the class member `name`) anymore, since you can always ask the service loader for an appropriate instance. (If you do so at some place in your code, you will already know for which name you just asked.) If so desired, you can also add more logic to this `JsonServiceLoader`, such as caching.

Ultimately, it all depends on how much information you want to process around your `Module` and how much of this information you want the `Module` implementations to handle and how much of it you want the service framework to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can pass the list into the constructor of the parent class and add subclass itself to the list in the constructor method.
Just like this

```java
public abstract class Module {

    public final String name;

    public Module(String name, List<Module> list) {
        this.name = name;
        list.add(this);
    }

    public abstract void execute();
}
```

```java
private static final List<Module> MODULES = new ArrayList<>();

public void init(){
    new Mod1(MODULES);
}
```

Comment: This merely saves a few bytes of code per line in `Module#init`. The intention of this question, however, is to find a solution that does not rely on modification of the `Module` class in order to locate its implementations.